# how to optimize repetitive addition

Tags: c

```
#define NULL 0

int main()
{
    int *array1=NULL,*array2=NULL;
    int x =add(array1[0],array2[0]);
    int y =add(array1[1],array2[7]); 
    int x =add(array1[2],array2[3]);
    int y =add(array1[3],array2[4]);
    int x =add(array1[4],array2[6]);
    int y =add(array1[5],array2[1]); 
    int x =add(array1[6],array2[5]);
    int y =add(array1[7],array2[2]);
    ................
    ................
    int x =add(array1[252],array2[0]);
    int y =add(array1[253],array2[7]); 
    int x =add(array1[254],array2[3]);
    int y =add(array1[255],array2[4]);
}
```

Basically index for `array1` is incrementing by 1 starting from 0 to till 255
but the index for `array2` is fixed from 0 to 7. So I want to optimize this multiple addition. How to optimize this?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense since you seem to be redefining `x` and `y`.

Comment: yeah, remove all the previous lines in `main()` except the last two. done.

Comment: accessing array[1] will crash

Comment: @PeterMiehle: If that was guaranteed by UB to crash, it would be better. But it is not. Note that already array_[0] is UB btw (dereference _null pointer_).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you can is

```
int j = 0,order[] = {0,7,3,4,6,1,5,2};
for(int i = 0;i <256; i +=2)
{
    int x =add(array1[i],array2[order[j%8]]);
    j++;
    int y =add(array1[i+1],array2[order[j%8]]);
    j++;
}
```

**UPDATE**
alternate solution can be (if you want without using i+=2)

```
int j = 0,order[] = {0,7,3,4,6,1,5,2};
for(int i = 0;i <256; i ++)
{
    int x =add(array1[i],array2[order[j%8]]);
    j++;
    i++; 
    if(i>=256) break;  //Improves it if you have non even condition
    int y =add(array1[i],array2[order[j%8]]);
    j++;
}
```

**edit by sam** 
**Now i want to compare this two values of x and y and selecting value based on comparision**

```
     CurrentTre=256;
     if (x > y)
     {
     *array3[0]= x;
     *array4[CurrentTre +0] = 0;
     }
     else
     {
     *array3[i] = y;
     *array4[CurrentTre + 0] = 1;
     }
     ..........
     ..........
     if (x > y)
     {
     *array3[0]= x;
     *array4[CurrentTre +127] = 254;
     }
     else
     {
     *array3[i] = y;
     *array4[CurrentTre + 127] = 255;
     }
     /////////////
     my approach is this way

     if (x > y)
     {
     *array3[i]= x;
     *array4[int CurrentTre +i] = int number[i]<<1;
     }
     else
     {
     array3[i] = y;
     array4[int CurrentTre + i] = int number[i]<<1|1;
     }
} //end function main
```

**I want to optimize the code my optimization is  given below 
   please check whether am i doing right or not..?**

```
uint32 even_number[255] ={0};
uint32 loop_index1=0;
uint32 loop_index2=0;

uint16 order[256]={0,7,3,4,6,1,5,2,4,3,7,0,1,6,2,5,7,0,4,3,2,5,1,6,3,4,0
,7,6,1,5,2,4,3,7,0,1,6,2,5,0,7,3,4,5,2,6,1,3,4,0,7,6,1,5,2,7,0,4,3,2,5
,1,6,5,2,6,1,0,7,3,4,1,6,2,5,4,3,7,0,2,5,1,6,7,0,4,3,6,1,5,2,3,4,0,7,1
,6,2,5,4,3,7,0,5,2,6,1,0,7,3,4,6,1,5,2,3,4,0,7,2,5,1,6,7,0,4,3,3,4,0,7
,6,1,5,2,7,0,4,3,2,5,1,6,4,3,7,0,1,6,2,5,0,7,3,4,5,2,6,1,7,0,4,3,2,5,1
,6,3,4,0,7,6,1,5,2,0,7,3,4,5,2,6,1,4,3,7,0,1,6,2,5,6,1,5,2,3,4,0,7,2,5
,1,6,7,0,4,3,1,6,2,5,4,3,7,0,5,2,6,1,0,7,3,4,2,5,1,6,7,0,4,3,6,1,5,2,3
,4,0,7,5,2,6,1,0,7,3,4,1,6,2,5,4,3,7,0}; //all 256 values



for(loop_index1;loop_index1<256;loop_index1++)
   {    
    m0= (CurrentState[loop_index1]+Branch[order[loop_index2]]);
loop_index2++;
loop_index1++;
if(loop_index1>=256) 
break;

m1= (CurrentState[loop_index1]+Branch[order[loop_index2]]);

loop_index2++;

if (mo > m1)
 {
 NextState[loop_index1]= m0;
 SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + loop_index1] =
 even_number[loop_index1]<<1;
 }
else
{
 NextState[loop_index1] = StateMetric1;
 SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + loop_index1] = 
  even_number[loop_index1<<1|1;
}
}
```

Comment: `y=array1[i+1]` and  `for(...,i+=2)`

Comment: @PeterMiehle I fixed it too, but since number is even, your way is better

Comment: @Lundin ok, but for y, you cant simply use index2+1 as index of second array you need to get it back from order.

Comment: why i is incremented by 2..?

Comment: @sam example a begining i = 0, for x we are using 0, but in the same loop, for y we are putting i+1 which is 1 as needed, now if we increment only by 1 x will be using 1, but we need it it to be 2, hence we increment it by 2 as by using array[i+1] does not increment i.

Comment: @sam I am having difficulty in understanding, can you please explain more and add more code (like how you declared x, and y so I can compile it)

Comment: I have added unoptimized and optimized code please check whether my understanding is correct or not ..please help..

Comment: @sam moderators had  rejected your edit before I got here. I have copied your edits from history. But Next Time please post the code in your post and notify me by adding a comment on my post. Now I am going to read it.

Comment: @sam are mo and m0 different variables?

Comment: sorry for typo both are same

Comment: @sam what are variables like CurrentTrellis for, their initial values and what you want to do with them?

Comment: @sam please tell what you want to do in if else part of code, like what are those 2 arrays for and how should data go in them.

Comment: for currentTrellis value will be 256 for first cycle, for second cycle onwards it will vary from 0 to 256. for (k=0;k<256;k++) currentTrellis =k*256;

Comment: for if and else part i want to compare m0 and m1 values based on comparison values i ant assign values next state and survivor state.

Comment: @sam I saw your other post too. You have done horrible coding and explaination. Your 2 snippets that you have added to my answer and 1 in other post are aiming to do different things. Though code is most likely simple but the way you have put it and explained, makes me very confused. For instance in your comment you post currenttrellis will be 256 in first cycle, and onwards it will vary from 0 to 256, but you did something else. From nowhere even_number loop came. Erase your post with clean code, detailed comments, and specifics such as if your unoptimized code works according to your way...

Answer (score 1):

first step:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i+=8) {
  x = add(array1[i],   array2[0]);
  y = add(array1[i+1], array2[7]);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer

```
    int *array1 = NULL, *array2 = NULL;
    int *ptr1 = array1;
    int x = add(*ptr1++, array2[0]);
    int y = add(*ptr1++, array2[7]); 
    int x = add(*ptr1++, array2[3]);
    int y = add(*ptr1++, array2[4]);
    int x = add(*ptr1++, array2[6]);
    int y = add(*ptr1++, array2[1]); 
    int x = add(*ptr1++, array2[5]);
    int y = add(*ptr1++, array2[2]);
    ................
    ................
    int x = add(*ptr1++, array2[0]);
    int y = add(*ptr1++, array2[7]); 
    int x = add(*ptr1++, array2[3]);
    int y = add(*ptr1++, array2[4]);
```

But remember *[premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)*.

Before optimizing measure and make certain you need optimizing the accesses to the array.

After optimizing measure to make certain the optimization had any effect.