# How to optimize repettitive add,cmpare and select in this c code

Tags: c

```
   int main()
   {
   int32 *CurrentState = NULL, 
   int32 *NextState = NULL,    
   uint32 m0,m1;                          
   int32 *Branch = NULL;                                 
   uint8 *SurvivorState = NULL;  
   uint32  CurrentTrellis   

   m0 = add(CurrentState[0], Branch[0]);
   m1 = add(CurrentState[1], Branch[7]);
   if(m0 > m1) 
   {
    NextState[0] = m0;
    SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 0;
   }
   else
   { 
   NextState[0] = m1;
   SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 1;
   }  
  m0 = add(CurrentState[2], Branch[4]);
  m1 = add(CurrentState[3], Branch[5]);
  if(m0 > m1) 
  {
  NextState[0] = m0;
  SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 2;
  }
  else
  { 
  NextState[0] = m1;
  SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 3;
  }
  m0 = add(CurrentState[4], Branch[6]);
  m1 = add(CurrentState[5], Branch[1]);       
  if(m0 > m1) 
  {
  NextState[0] = m0;
  SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 4;
  }
  else
  { 
  NextState[0] = m1;
  SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 5;
  }
  ................
  ................
  m0 = add(CurrentState[254], Branch[5]);
  m1 = add(CurrentState[255], Branch[2]);

  if(m0 > m1) 
  {
  NextState[0] = m0;
  SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 254;
  }
  else
  { 
  NextState[0] = m1;
  SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 255;
  }
```

}

**Basically index for CurrentState is incrementing by 1 starting from 0 to till 255(total 256 values) but the index for branch  is fixed from 0 to 7(total 8 values). So I want to optimize this multiple addition,compare and select..How to optimize this**

**first optimization i tried with using ternary operator which will replace if and else loop but still i need more optimization how to do it ..?**

Comment: First optimization, **INDENT YOUR CODE**, that will not improve performance or anything, but your code really needs it, specially if you want others to read it.

Comment: Is this the question that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708757/how-to-optimize-repetitive-addition) might grow into? Very strange, please don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
m0 = add(CurrentState[0], Branch[0]);
m1 = add(CurrentState[1], Branch[7]);
if(m0 > m1) 
{
NextState[0] = m0;
SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 0;
}
else
{ 
NextState[0] = m1;
SurvivorState[CurrentTrellis + 0] = 1;
}
```

This repetitive part of code should become a function and the changing numbers (indices) should become its parameters. The variables `CurrentState`, `Branch`, `NextState`, `SurvivorState` and `CurrentTrellis` can become global variables or parameters, depending on their overall usage.

If there is a pattern for choosing the indices (I could not find any), you could call the function in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your sugesstion but repetitive function call will increase CPU cycle count please suggest me some alternative methods

Comment: Well, then make it a macro instead of function, so it gets expanded by the preprocessor. Your current code looks very unmaintainable. And the best choice nowadays for a repetitive task is to make it running parallel. http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/